# invalid operation on binary have int and complex int

Tags: c

I am getting the following errors (and more syntax errors which I can correct). Any idea why and how to resolve it?

```
In function 'main':|

21|error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'int' and 'complex int')|


24|error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'complex int' and 'int')|

26|error: invalid operands to binary <= (have 'int' and 'complex int')|

28|error: invalid operands to binary <= (have 'int' and 'complex int')|
```

The source:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int t,flag,i,j,k,no[20];
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
  scanf("%d",&no[i]);

  for(j=1;j<=t;j++){

    if(no[j]%3==0){
    for(i=1;i<=no[j];i++){
      printf("5");}
      printf("\n");}


    else{
            i=1;
            flag=0;
    while(flag==0){
    if(no[j]<5i)
        printf("-1");

    else if((no[j]-5i)%3==0){
        flag=1;
        for(k=1;k<=(no[j]-5i);k++)
            printf("5");
        for(k=1;k<=5i;k++)
        printf("3");}
        else
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Is `5i` a typo, if not what did you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5i` is a [complex number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexNumber.html) ([At least in gcc it is](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html)).  Just use `5`.   (Or `5*i` since you say you meant to multiply.)

---

In the future you can solve problems like this yourself with a few simple steps:

1. Read the error:

   `21|error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'int' and 'complex int')|`
2. Find the line:

   `if(no[j]<5i)`
3. Think:

   *The operands to `<` are `no[j]` and `5i`.  I see `no[j]` is declared as `int` so it must be treating `5i` as "complex int"*
4. Plus a little searching to verify:

   ["c language complex numbers"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c+language+complex+numbers) didn't turn up anything, but ["gcc support for complex numbers"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gcc+support+for+complex+numbers) did.

Comment: no look at the code i want it to multiply i by 5..as in i want to compare the values with 5i as i increases from 1 onwards.. so i=1 , 5 then i=2 ..10 and so on...

Comment: @user3424954 `5*i`, then

Comment: Then use 5*i.  C does not understand algebraic notation.

Comment: Both the `i` suffix and the support for *integer* complex types are gcc-specific extensions (floating-point complex types are standard as of C99, and optional as of C11).